# convert string to 2d array python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a text file and I want to convert the below string to a 2d array.

File Data:

```
[[],['java','j2ee','spring'],['.net','c#','mysql'],['php','mysql']]
```

My Code:

```
with open("test.txt") as myfile:
    sentences = np.array(myfile.readline(),dtype=object)

print(sentences)
```

It returns the below array

```
array("[[],['java','j2ee','spring'],['.net','c#','mysql'],['php','mysql']]", dtype=object)
```

I want following output

```
array([[],['java','j2ee','spring'],['.net','c#','mysql'],['php','mysql']],dtype=object)
```

Comment: [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: Why would you save your data like that? Why not comma separated?

Comment: You could use json.load  https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Thank you @OlvinRoght, literal_eval() worked.

Comment: You can get a list of lists from that, but not a 2d array,

Answer (score -1):

You could use `sentences=np.array(eval(sentences[0]))`
Warning:
as mentioned in the comments, `eval` can pose a security risk. Use with caution.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I can only guess, but maybe because "code only" answers (sorry I don't count the 3 additional words) are not really appreciated on SO. And some people downvote answers on questions that should be closed. This question is a duplicate, meaning there already good answers available. Repeating it here is not really useful. Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI: It's also flagged as Low Quality Post, where it's currently being reviewed. It might help to read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: By the way, `eval()` is considered bad, since it is an unsafe function (security risk). Especially when using it on external data, such as data read from a file. You should really warn about that if you advice someone to use it.